# iOS UITableViewController static tableView does not scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, iqkeyboardmanager

I have an Xcode 8 project and whenever I instantiate a `UITableViewController`, I simply cannot scroll the content. I have made sure that:

- `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `TRUE` (on the tableView)
- `scrollEnabled` is set to `TRUE` (on the tableView)
- there are no overlayed views which have either `userInteractionEnabled` set to `TRUE` or a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `cancelsTouchesInView` set to `TRUE`
- there are no small views which have `clipsToBounds` set to `FALSE` and may block the scroll
- the table view height is not bigger that the content's
- the bouncing + vertical bouncing is set to TRUE
- I'm using `IQKeyboardManager`. I have made sure that this bug is not caused by the library, by purposely disabling it.
- this is not related to orientation either. I have tried with Portrait-only and I have constantly changed the orientation to check the results.

It's interesting that if I tap a `UITextField` from one of the static cells, the `IQKeyboardManager` scrolls the content a little bit down. So the table view is scrollable, but I cannot do it by normal swiping.

Furthermore, I thought that this may be related to my specific class, maybe I'm doing something wrong... BUT I've even tried to instantiate a blank `UITableViewController` at the first initialisation point of the app with 5 sections, but it didn't work.

Please, keep all of this information in mind, what can I do? I'm using iOS 10 and iPhone 6s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after more than 3 days of daily debugging, I found out the problem ...

This is definitely the trickiest bug I've ever encountered, but it seems that Cocoapods power comes with responsibility. I've imported the following library:

`https://github.com/shaps80/iMessageStyleReveal`

And unfortunately the library itself breaks the table view scroll. When I debugged the actuals views, it was even more hard to notice the added gesture recognizer of the library, as it had a common name and `cancelTouchesInView` set to FALSE. The actual problem was inside the extension, where the UITableView methods were overriden.

Removed it and everything works again. Phew.

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, make sure that bounces and bounce vertically are turned on. Bouncing causes your table view to not just scroll on overflow. But whenever.

[image: Near the Bottom is the Bounce/bounces option.]

Comment: Unfortunately, I forgot to mention I checked this too :(

Comment: Can you post your table views properties in an image.

Comment: what about your code?(using your exact properties scrolling works for me)

Comment: It's not about the code. I disabled all the code from 'viewDidLoad', 'viewWillAppear' etc. The same result. Heck, I even created an empty UITableViewController, with no class attached to it, set it as the root view controller of the app, it's not swiping! I believe it's a global problem inside the project..

Comment: try creating a new project. Also see if this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793505/uitableviewcontroller-tableview-wont-scroll?rq=1

Comment: That link wasn't helpful :( And I have tried to create a new project, it works on the new one. Apparently, all the static UITableViews are stuck like this in my app. I've been trying to find the cause, maybe it's a nasty extension I thought, but I was not lucky.